# What does GL_TEXTURE_3D mean?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, opengl, graphics

As I know the texture is just an image (absolutely 2D), so why do we have GL_TEXTURE_3D? What does it mean? and usage?

Comment: It's for 3d textures - you are wrong that textures are always 2d.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A texture is not absolutely 2d. Most of the time it is 2d but you can also have 1d textures (a line) and 3d textures (a volume). A 3D texture is accessed using three texture coordinates. You can use it when your 3d model can be clipped by a plane. Then instead of seeing the other side of the object (the object is hollow), you can use a 3d texture to make a solid object and view what the plane clipped. So for example, if you model a cell phone and you cut it in half, instead of seeing the backside, you can see the circuitry inside.

Comment: It should be pointed out, that applying a 3D texture doesn't make solid models in OpenGL. If you'd simply cut the object using clip planes, you'd still only see the surfaces being textured. However using a volume raycasting shader you can render solids. A better example of a cellphone and circurity would have been a CT scan. Google for "Voxelman" to get an idea.

Answer (score 4):

Textures in OpenGL can be 1D, 2D, or 3D. 3D textures are, AFAIK, not that much used by games, but more by things like scientific visualization applications. E.g. you have a dataset with 3D coordinates (x,y,z) and some value (v). Then you can upload the dataset (or more likely, a reduced size version of it due to memory constraints) to the GPU and visualize it in some way (e.g. creating a 2D slice from a 3D texture is VERY fast compared to creating the 2D slice as a texture on the CPU and uploading it).

Comment: There are also cubemaps and 1D and 2D array textures too.